# postfix mail server rewrites the email

Tags: email, smtp, mime, mail-server, postfix-mta

I have the following problem:
postfix changes the email.
the email sent to postfix, and the email received as a postfix filter are not the same.
It happens only if the email has illegal [header: body] fields according to the RFC.

if one of his header [key: body] expandes to more then 1 line with no spaces,
postfix will interpret the rest as the body, for example:

```
...
References: <some_email@mail.gmail.com>
<sldkfjsdfjklnf@at-temp.com>
From: name@example.com <name@example.com>
...
```

will be rewriten by postifx as:

```
...
References: <some_email@mail.gmail.com>
Message-Id: <3tBfNB3zbzfz6vP3@debian8>
Date: Sun, 6 Nov 2016 17:18:18 +0200 (IST)
From: name2@example.com

<sldkfjsdfjklnf@at-temp.com>
From: name@example.com <name@example.com>
...
```

In my filter I need to have original email,
How can I configure postfix to not modify the email?

thanks,
Lior